# Paginação ASP.NET Core - PagedList.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou criando um projeto de estudo de ASP.NET core, e ao utilizar a biblioteca de paginação `PagedList.Core`, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro ao rodar o comando `dotnet run`:

> Startup.cs(49,35): error CS0246: O nome do tipo ou do namespace "IActionContextAccessor" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?) [C:\projetos\net\osnet\osnet.csproj]
> Startup.cs(49,59): error CS0246: O nome do tipo ou do namespace "ActionContextAccessor" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?) [C:\projetos\net\osnet\osnet.csproj]
>
> Ocorreu uma falha no build. Corrija os erros de build e execute novamente.

O que poderia ser ?

Meu método `ConfigureServices` do arquivo `Startup.cs` está assim:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
       
        var connection = Configuration["ConexaoSqlite:SqliteConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<OsNetContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(connection)
        );
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>(); // <= Add this
        
    }
```

Comment: Existe algum erro no build?

Comment: Bom dia amigo, o erro no Build é esse mencionado na pergunta: Startup.cs(49,35): error CS0246: O nome do tipo ou do namespace "IActionContextAccessor" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?) [C:\projetos\net\osnet\osnet.csproj]
Startup.cs(49,59): error CS0246: O nome do tipo ou do namespace "ActionContextAccessor" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?) [C:\projetos\net\osnet\osnet.csproj]

Ocorreu uma falha no build. Corrija os erros de build e execute novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se o seu projeto está referenciando o assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll`

O namespace da interface é `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure`

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar